# Drawing Custom Shapes and Lines Using Canvas and Path in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

> Drawing Custom Shapes and Lines Using Canvas and Path in Flutter.
> I want to Draw Custom Shapes and Lines Using Canvas and Path in Flutter. I want to do this with GestureDetector. I want to start at 0,0 and draw back to 0,0. In short, I want to draw and create the shape I want by hand. How can I do it.

[image]

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

double x = 100;
double y = 200;
double X_Position = 0.00;
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
double Y_Position = 0.00;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final key = GlobalKey();
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(X_Position.toString()),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onPanStart: (details) {
              Offset position = details.localPosition;
              setState(() {
                X_Position = position.dx;
                Y_Position = position.dy;
              });
            },
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              Offset position = details.localPosition;
              setState(() {
                X_Position = position.dx;
                Y_Position = position.dy;
                print(X_Position);
                print(Y_Position);
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              key: key,
              width: 500,
              height: 500,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                // Inner yellow container
                builder: (_, constraints) => Container(
                  width: constraints.widthConstraints().maxWidth,
                  height: constraints.heightConstraints().maxHeight,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: CustomPaint(painter: FaceOutlinePainter()),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FaceOutlinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // TODO: draw something with canvas
    final paint = Paint();
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 4.0;
    paint.color = Colors.indigo;

    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(X_Position, size.height / 2),
      Offset(Y_Position, size.height / 2),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FaceOutlinePainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

> For example, I want to draw a square on the screen. I will draw the square randomly by hand. While drawing lines on the screen, I will keep the x and y coordinates of each point I pass in an array. I want to draw with the help of offset. Their values should come from the gesturedetector. I want to make my shapes using only canvas.drawLine.

Answer (score 0):

Using global variables in Flutter is a no-no.

1. Create some kind of immutable Model class for your drawing. Make sure to implement value-based equality (override `operator==`),
2. Declare current value of model in your `State`,
3. Pass this model to your `CustomPainter`,
4. Implement `CustomPainter.shouldRepaint` - when model is the same, no need to repaint
5. `setState` your model in response to gestures.